# How to generate UUIDs in JS or React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my `React` app, I want to do optimistic updates to create a responsive experience for my users.

Having said that I want to send a user entry to my backend with an ID that will be used so that there won't be a different Id for the user's entry next time he/she uses the app. For example, if the user enters a comment, I want to assign its ID with a real `UUID` and then send it to my API.

I understand `JavaScript` or `React` don't really have a built-in way to generate `UUID`/`GUID` values. I've seen many articles that produce randomized values that look like `UUID`/`GUID`'s but they really are not and I don't want to use them as ID's for user entries.

How do I get real `UUID`/`GUID` values in my frontend? Do I call my backend API to get them? I can create an endpoint in my API that spits out 10 or 20 `GUID`'s at a time and I can store them for future use in my frontend but this sounds a bit absurd.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel here as I'm not the first person to face this scenario. How do I get real `UUID` values on my frontend?

Comment: Bundle https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid into your app and do it client-side? at 7 million downloads a week, it's kind of the de facto uuid library of choice.

Comment: Thank you! Just looked at the page and they seem to comply with IETF standards so I assume they're real UUID's.

Comment: they better be, tens of thousand of production sites rely on it =D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a GUID / UUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-do-i-create-a-guid-uuid)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [uuid npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid). You probably want to use a v4 UUID. (Previous UUID versions use things like a timestamp or network card MAC address as seeds to the random generator).

Comment: Cool! Are they real UUID's? A quick look suggests they are. I wasn't aware of this package.

Comment: I haven't used that package in production, but it worked well for my testing, and it has a lot of downloads, so I'd trust it.

Answer (score 5):

just use **crypto.randomUUID()**

available in most of the newer browser versions.

Comment: I think this could work. However not all environments use the latest and the greatest browsers and so, although this works, it it not a universal solution for all cases at the moment. But it's a great thing to know and share!

Answer (score 4):

You're probably just fine generating them client-side - it takes many, many UUIDs before you even approach a 1 in a million rate of collision (citing the answer below).

This answer has several solutions to generating them client-side in a way that complies with [RFC4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt):

[Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript#answer-2117523)

Alternatively, you could generate temporary optimistic IDs and then replace them when you get a response from the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've seen so many articles like the post you've referenced. I'm just not crazy about using such an approach. Assigning some ID and then replacing is doing the work twice. If those are my options, I think I'd rather create an API end point that spits out UUID values, say 20 at a time. I can then use them in different parts of my app because I want to do optimistic updates in multiple modules. When I'm down to 2 UUID's in my Redux store, I can make another call to get 20 fresh ones. Why not use this approach?

Comment: Well, I guess I'd say that the approach adds complexity to the code without generating value (compared to generating them client-side and simply using those). Plus, what happens when the ID-provisioning service needs to scale? There's still the same chances of a collision. To be clear, I agree that using a temporary ID also adds complexity; I'd advocate for simply generating them client-side and using those values.

Comment: The downside of generating them client-side is that a malicious actor can repost and change your client generated uuid to an existing uuid, and that could mess up your primary keys. (lots of assumptions in that, but that's why I generate them server side.)